# Angular HttpClient POST request not interacting with Spring Controller

Tags: angular, spring, rest, angular-httpclient

I'm having trouble making a POST request from an Angular frontend service class to my spring backend controller.

I am trying to get a log.info message to display from the controller, but it isn't working unless I manually use Swagger to make the call.

I don't think the issue is with the Java Rest Controller as Swagger can make the call to it.

I don't think there is an issue with my service class post request not being called, as I'm able to get the console.log message to display.

I don't think there is an issue with my resourceUrl in my service class as that is working fine with other REST calls.

I think it's something with how I am formatting my postRequest.

(Typescript service class)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SERVER_API_URL } from 'app/app.constants';
import { DataModel} from 'app/shared/model/data-model.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DataModelService {
  public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'services/api/data-model';

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}

  postRequest(dataModel: DataModel, status: string): Observable<DataModel> {
    console.log('post rest service called with status ' + status);
    return this.http.post<DataModel>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${status}`, dataModel);
  }
```

(Typescript component class)

```
export class Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...

  constructor( protected dataModelService DataModelService) { }

  userClicks(dataModel: DataModel): void {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    console.log('button clicked');
    console.log(dataModel);
    /* eslint-enable no-console */

    this.dataModelService.postRequest(dataModel, 'Status changed');
  }
```

(Java Spring REST Controller)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestResource {

    @PostMapping("/data-model/{status}")
    public ResponseEntity<DataModelDTO> create(@Valid @RequestBody DataModelDTO dataModelDTO, @PathVariable String status) throws URISyntaxException{
        log.info(dataModelDTO.toString() + " status " + status);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dataModelDTO);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you opened the Dev tools of your browser? Is there any error? Does the http request sent looks good? Are you suubscribing to the `Observable` of your POST?

Comment: OK I am looking at the Dev Tools in the Network tab and I am not seeing the REST call being triggered (there is no error). I am not subscribing, let me add my Typescript component class to help..

Comment: Please add code where you consume your POST req.

Comment: I added my component class.

Comment: Angular is searching the service under SERVER_API_URL + 'services/api/data-model';  In spring it seams that "services" is missing

Comment: I don't think that is my issue, as other REST calls are working that are using the same URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to the `Observable`, otherwise the request won't be triggered. Observables are "lazy".

```js
this.dataModelService.postRequest(dataModel, 'Status changed')
  .subscribe(response => {
    // Do something with the response optionally
  }, error => {
    // Do something if an error occurs
  });
```